# Python Import failing

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple structure of my Flask application and couldn't make imports.

```
FlaskFolder
__init__.py (includes db parameters for flask SqlAlchemy)
dbase.py (Trying to import DB variable from __init__.py and its failing.
```

In my `__init__.py` I am trying to import like `"from FlaskFolder import dbase"` within the same folder and I couldn't do it.

In my dbase.py I am trying to import like `"from FlaskFolder import db"` (db is a class in `__init__.py`) but couldn't do it.

```
Error: No module named FlaskFolder
```

Please advise how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Tried that....its not duplicate

Comment: can you show the dbase.py and __init__.py or give us more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is `circular import`.

First, when `from FlaskFolder import dbase` in `__init__.py`，program will 
execute `dbase.py` file. The file will execute `from FlaskFolder import db`.
This will go to `__init__.py`, execute the `from FlaskFolder import dbase`.
And balalala....

This has 2 solutions.

1. in `__init__.py`, let `from FlaskFolder import dbase` after flask SqlAlchemy db define.
2. define flask SqlAlchemy db in `dbbase.py`. and import it in `__init__.py`

Comment: Yes this is circular import and that's the reason I was trying to import it in end of the file. It worked. Thanks

Comment: @Anonymous Coder, No thanks.